# Removing line from CSV if a date has passed

Tags: php

I'm opening a two-column CSV with states in one column and a delivery date in m/d/y format in the other. I'd like to remove duplicate state entries that have a date older than the most recent corresponding date.

For example, if the CSV contains:

```
CA,1/5/16
CA,4/8/15
CA,3/2/15
OR,3/4/15
OK,3/4/14
```

... I'd only want to store:

```
CA,1/5/16
OR,3/4/15
OK,3/4/14
```

Then, I want to compare the delivery dates in this new array to the current date and only show the states that have dates in the past (only OR and OK). To provide context, a delivery to a state comes in different parts, and I only want to list states with fully-delivered shipments.

I'm stuck on the comparing and removing dates part, but think I have the rest. So far, I have:

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row=0;
    $csv_delivered = array();

    while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $date=$line_of_text[1];

        if(\DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y',$date) < new \DateTime()){
        //date is in the past
            $csv_delivered[] = $line_of_text;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle); 

    foreach ($csv_delivered as $delivered) {
        $states_delivered.= $delivered[0].","; //state
    } 
}

?>

    <p>Delivered: <?php echo $states_delivered; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right,

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $row=0;
    $csv_delivered = array();
    $state_date = array();     // holds date of last occurence
    $now = new \DateTime();

    while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // ignore data that are in the future
        if ($state_date_min[$state]>$now) continue;

        // prepare
        $date=$line_of_text[1];
        $state=$line_of_text[0];
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y',$date);

        // store if not existing or overwrite if this one is newer
        if (!isset($state_date[$state]) || $date>$state_date[$state]) {
            $csv_delivered[$state] = $line_of_text;
            $state_date[$state] = $date;
        }

    }
    fclose($handle); 

    foreach ($csv_delivered as $state => $delivered) {
        $states_delivered.= $delivered[0].","; //state
    } 
}

?>

    <p>Delivered: <?php echo $states_delivered; ?></p>
```

Remember the date for each state and store if not existing or overwrite  if newer. Do ignore all data that are in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Very close - this cleans the data for the first step, but no longer checks to see if the date is in the past.

Comment: This still shows CA (1/5/16), but correctly removes any future states that _aren't_ duplicated. It shouldn't show 1/5/16 since it's a future date.

Comment: Your example data contain `1/5/16`, too.

Comment: Right, but it's a future date that would complete the CA delivery, so it shouldn't show as a completed delivery.

Comment: But okay, if you ONLY want to use data that are in the past, that makes the script much shorter.

Comment: Adapted... but remember that SO's goal is to provide knowledge, not to write code for some people.

Comment: Yeah, but I'll reuse the data for other things, like a separate list of states with upcoming deliveries since some states would have no deliveries at all. You've got me most of the way there, though - thank you!

Comment: Asking the same question as @charlesrockbass...thanks for accepting.

Comment: @charlesrockbass I just joined, I guess my reputation isn't high enough? Sorry, I'll come back to upvote.

Comment: @foolsgoat Oh, my bad, hadn't notice that. Welcome to SO, then! ^_^

Comment: There is no time limit on that =) Welcome, too.